# Remove dots and space between item and page number in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm preparing a document and want to remove space (except for maybe a `\qquad`) and dotted lines between the entries in my table of contents and the page numbers.  would like my table of contents to go from looking like this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

It's only because I chose chapter and section titles poorly that the numbers are lined up; ideally, they'd be a constant distance from the end of the chapter/section title, rather than vertically aligned with each other.

This is very similar but not quite the same task as some other questions here, and I feel certain that a sufficiently competent TeXer could use those answers, and the information in the [`titletoc`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package to do this, but I just don't understand it.

My file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,twocolumn]{scrreprt}

\KOMAoption{DIV}{calc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A}

\section{A1}

\chapter{B}

\section{B1}

\end{document}
```

Ideally I (and you) wouldn't have to recreate the Koma-Script table of contents style from scratch, but could instead just modify this value. Also ideally this answer would be portable to documents on other paper sizes and classes -- but I started with scrreprt, because that's what I'm actually working with. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This should work in Koma and standard classes:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\renewcommand\cftchapleader{\qquad}
\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\qquad}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecleader{\qquad}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A}
\section{A1}
\chapter{B}
\section{B1}
\subsection{B11}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: There's a bug, I'm afraid... Try it with a multiple-word section or chapter title, and you'll see that it goes haywire, stretching the spaces between words out madly

Comment: Yes, because still want to fill the line and these spaces are now the only stretchable places. Surely there is a better solution,  but one obvious solution is avoid completely the stretchable spaces in the toc titles, e.g.:  `\chapter[\mbox{foo bar}]{foo bar}`

Comment: In case of the multiline titles in the ToC (always ugly), also could work a `\parbox`, e.g.:work `\chapter[\parbox{3cm}{foo foo foo foo foo foo foo}]{foo ...}`